How to integrate Flutter app with azure ad b2c authentication
Tried integrating azure ad b2c with flutter app with mobile number as signup, made custom ui for the login_screen.dart and otp_screen.dart getting errors a lot and tried to work on those errors but didn't get any result. Have zero knowledge on doing this, this is the first time. Took help from ChatGPT.
Built an authentication api using node.js with express because it was easy and understandable hosted the server and it is working. There are no resources showing how to integrate azure ad b2c with flutter application except the one with the embedded web view which is not viable because I want the azure ad b2c service to be integrated with the custom ui.
The dependencies used are flutter_azure_b2c, flutter_appauth, msal_flutter, http,
Will provide login_screen.dart, otp_screen.dart and server.js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'otp_screen.dart';
import 'registration_screen.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _phoneController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 40.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              Center(
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/usersigninpage.png',
                    height: 190,
                    width: 390,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 35),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Divider(
                      thickness: 1.5,
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  const Text(
                    'Log in or Sign Up',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Divider(
                      thickness: 1.5,
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              const Text(
                'Verify your mobile number to access our services',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black54),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: _phoneController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: [
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),
                      ],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Text('', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
                              SizedBox(width: 8),
                              Text('+91', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Enter Mobile Number',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your mobile number';
                        } else if (value.length != 10) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid 10-digit number';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          _navigateToOtpScreen();
                        }
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(160, 34, 45, 45),
                        minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Continue',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'New user?',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 8),
                          Text(
                            'Register with Tenant App by clicking below button',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 14),
                    OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => RegistrationScreen(phoneNumber: _phoneController.text),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                        side: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(160, 34, 45, 45), width: 2),
                        minimumSize: const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Register',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(160, 34, 45, 45),
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToOtpScreen() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => OTPScreen(
          mobileNumber: _phoneController.text,
          onVerificationSuccess: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => RegistrationScreen(phoneNumber: _phoneController.text),
              ),
            );
          },
          phoneNumber: _phoneController.text,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _phoneController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

This is login_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '/widgets/custom_button.dart';

class OTPScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mobileNumber;
  final Function onVerificationSuccess;

  const OTPScreen({
    super.key, 
    required this.mobileNumber, 
    required this.onVerificationSuccess, required String phoneNumber, 
  });

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _OTPScreenState createState() => _OTPScreenState();
}

class _OTPScreenState extends State<OTPScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _otpController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _otpFocusNode = FocusNode();
  bool _isResendButtonEnabled = false;
  int _secondsRemaining = 60;
  Timer? _timer;
  String? _errorMessage;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _otpController.dispose();
    _otpFocusNode.dispose();
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startTimer();
  }

  void _startTimer() {
    setState(() {
      _isResendButtonEnabled = false;
      _secondsRemaining = 60;
    });

    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (_secondsRemaining > 0) {
        setState(() {
          _secondsRemaining--;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _isResendButtonEnabled = true;
        });
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

  Widget _buildOTPBox(int index) {
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          _otpController.text.length > index ? _otpController.text[index] : '',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.color?.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Login with OTP',
          style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.color),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            Text(
              'To confirm your email address, please enter the OTP we sent to +91 ${widget.mobileNumber}',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.color,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                _otpFocusNode.requestFocus();
              },
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: List.generate(6, (index) => _buildOTPBox(index)),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              controller: _otpController,
              focusNode: _otpFocusNode,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
              ],
              maxLength: 6,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {});
                if (value.length == 6) {
                  _otpFocusNode.unfocus();
                }
              },
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                height: 0.01,
              ),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                counterText: '',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            if (_errorMessage != null)
              Text(
                _errorMessage!,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            CustomButton(
              text: 'Login',
              onPressed: () {
                if (_otpController.text.isEmpty || _otpController.text.length < 6) {
                  setState(() {
                    _errorMessage = "Please enter the OTP";
                  });
                } else {
                  // Call the onVerificationSuccess callback if OTP is valid
                  widget.onVerificationSuccess();
                }
              },
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(160, 34, 45, 45),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(160, 34, 45, 45), width: 2),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: _isResendButtonEnabled ? () {
                    _startTimer();
                  } : null,
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Resend Code',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: _isResendButtonEnabled ? const Color.fromRGBO(160, 34, 45, 45) : Colors.grey,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              'Valid for $_secondsRemaining seconds',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is otp_screen.dart
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const BearerStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').BearerStrategy;

const app = express();

// Azure AD B2C configuration
const config = {
  identityMetadata: `https://${process.env.TENANT_NAME}.b2clogin.com/${process.env.TENANT_NAME}.onmicrosoft.com/${process.env.POLICY_NAME}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
  clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  audience: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  validateIssuer: false,
  passReqToCallback: false,
  loggingLevel: 'info'
};

const bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy(config, (token, done) => {
  // Here you can add custom token validation logic if needed
  done(null, { }, token);
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(bearerStrategy);

// Protect API endpoints
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false })(req, res, next);
});

// Sample protected route
app.get('/api/profile', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ name: req.authInfo.name, email: req.authInfo.preferred_username });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

This is server.js
TENANT_NAME={tenant-name}
POLICY_NAME={policy-name}
CLIENT_ID={client-id}
PORT=3000

This is .env
I know this is kind of lazy but fed up with the amount of time wasted. Tried several other ways but wanted to start from the fresh so provided the code in this way.
these are the common errors that I got

Build error exception in the azure ad b2c package got thid error
when flutter_azure_b2c and flutter_appauth dependencies are used
Authentication failed: Exception: Authentication failed: Invalid
argument(s): No host specified in URI
(tenant_name).onmicrosoft.com/(tenant_name)/ B2C_1
signupandsignin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize got this error when http
dependency is used.

